# Native libs + rvm

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, freebsd

I'm use Ruby 1.9.2 via RVM. Default version of ruby in system is 1.8.7. How to install libsvn-ruby (or any other native lib) for rvm-version of ruby?

(OS Ubuntu and FreeBSD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this gist could give some help: https://gist.github.com/766300